# Dynamically call a macro in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is possible to **dynamically call a macro** in Twig? For example, here is a template and a macro named "group" which builds a button group using `buttons` `array` argument. There are also two other macros, `save` and `delete`, for building save and delete buttons.

```
{# Make a group of buttons #}
{% macro group(buttons) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% import "::macros.html.twig" as macros %}

    {% set content = '' %}

    {% for button in buttons %}
        {% set content = content ~ button %}
    {% endfor %}

    {{ macros.el('div', content, { 'class' : 'btn-group' }) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}

{# Make a save button #}
{% macro save(attributes, size, image) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {{ _self.primary('save'|trans({}, 'buttons'), attributes, size, image) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}

{# Make a delete button #}
{% macro delete(attributes, size, image) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {{ _self.danger('delete'|trans({}, 'buttons'), attributes, size, image) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

This works fine passing an `array` of buttons:

```
{% import "::buttons.html.twig" as buttons %}
{% set items = [buttons.save, buttons.delete] %}
{{ buttons.group(items) }}
```

But i'd like to **pass macro names** to `group` macro:

```
{% import "::buttons.html.twig" as buttons %}
{{ buttons.group(['save', 'delete']) }}
```

and get `save` and `delete` macros called automatically. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

why not just do

```
{% import "::buttons.html.twig" as buttons %}
{{ buttons.group([buttons.save, buttons.delete]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an example of how to implement dynamic macro calling using attribute, checkout https://gist.github.com/tentacode/9728963b9f3a714608f3